# Alternative operations with switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

A silly program:

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main ()

  { 
     int a = 0;  

     cin >> a;    // Insert a number which is 0, 1 or 2.

     switch (a) 

       { 
         case 0  : cout << "The number is 0"; break;
         case 1  : cout << "The number is 1"; break;
         case 2  : cout << "The number is 2"; break;
       }

     return 0;

  }
```

This case is similar to an `if (a==0) {cout << "The number is 0";}` ect...

I know that the labels accepts only the type `constexpr`, but can be done something to change the == with others relational operators keeping using the switch conditional statement?

Please, keep answers as simple as you can. No strange advanced workarounds...

P.S. I know this program was easier without the switch and writing only
 `cout << "The number is " << a << ".";`. It's just a first approach to this statement.

Comment: "Please, keep answers as simple as you can. No strange advanced workarounds...I know this program was easier without the switch and writing only cout << "The number is " << a << ".";." - you've answered your own question. Other than that, what you write makes no sense.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Are you asking if you can do something like `case a > 10`, `case a < -5`? No, you can't.

Comment: @Quest Changing a == 0 with something like a > 0 as Barry said.

Comment: You know you can't - you write "I know that the labels accepts only the type constexpr"

Comment: @user3791372 Maybe changing the switch structure adding some code...

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli What's actually wrong with `if(a == 0) {} else if (a == 1) ...`?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ It's wrong because doesn't use the switch statement, as I asked. There're different ways of doing a thing, I'm just trying to discover them...

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli so read a programming book.

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli _"There're different ways of doing a thing, I'm just trying to discover them..."_, well `if/else if` is the right thing for what you asking, `switch/case` is no option since `a == 0` isn't  a const expression, period.

Comment: @user3791372 I've a programming book and it's C++ Primer 5th Edition by Lippman, Lajoie and Moo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  (Simple answer  :-)  )

The `switch` statement can be compiled a variety of ways.  The compiler could simple use a series of comparisons as you suggest, or it could use a jump table or a computed goto.  All of these options depend on `switch` being a known-at-compile-time list of explicit values, rather than relational operations.  If you have a series of "if the value is between a and b" type cases then `if...else if...` is most likely the way to go.